# Access Local Bean within a client using JBoss

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I have tried and run the [example](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/how-to-create-a-simple-ejb3-project-in-eclipse-jboss-7-1/) in order to apply `Remote` access to a Bean within a client.It runs properly, but now I would like to try the same process with a `Local` Bean. The name of the Local interface is now PersonalData and the bean implementation class is  `Firstbean`. Changing the method that creates the lookup name to:

```
private static String getLookupLocalName() {
            /*
            The app name is the EAR name of the deployed EJB without .ear suffix.
            Since we haven't deployed the application as a .ear,
            the app name for us will be an empty string
            */
                    String appName = "";

                    /* The module name is the JAR name of the deployed EJB
                    without the .jar suffix.
                    */
                    String moduleName = "EJBTest";

            /*AS7 allows each deployment to have an (optional) distinct name.
            This can be an empty string if distinct name is not specified.
            */
                    String distinctName = "";

                    // The EJB bean implementation class name
                    String beanName = FirstBean.class.getSimpleName();

                    // Fully qualified remote interface name
                    final String interfaceName = PersonalData.class.getName();

                    // Create a look up string name
                    String name = "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" +
                        distinctName    + "/" + beanName + "!" + interfaceName;

                    return name;
                }
```

and trying to access the Bean from main as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PersonalData bean = doLookup(getLookupLocalName());
    System.out.println(bean.getName()); 

    }
```

it throws a `NoSuchEJBException`:

```
   javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: No such EJB[appname=,modulename=EJBTest,distinctname=,beanname=FirstBean,viewclassname=com.al.ejbtest.PersonalData]
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.NoSuchEJBExceptionResponseHandler.processMessage(NoSuchEJBExceptionResponseHandler.java:64)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ChannelAssociation$ResponseReceiver.handleMessage(ChannelAssociation.java:395)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel$5.run(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:437)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:,modulename:EJBTest,distinctname:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@67a524a7
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:584)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.retryRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:206)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBReceiverInvocationContext.retryInvocation(EJBReceiverInvocationContext.java:95)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.NoSuchEJBExceptionResponseHandler.processMessage(NoSuchEJBExceptionResponseHandler.java:78)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ChannelAssociation$ResponseReceiver.handleMessage(ChannelAssociation.java:395)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel$5.run(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:437)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.NoSuchEJBExceptionResponseHandler$ResultProducer.getResult(NoSuchEJBExceptionResponseHandler.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:270)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:272)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(ReceiverInterceptor.java:132)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:260)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:399)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:140)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getName(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibytecode.client.EJBApplicationClient.main(EJBApplicationClient.java:20)
```

How can I use `Local` access to a bean with Jboss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correcty, you are trying to access to a Bean  through his Local interfce using a remote client and this is not possible.

The services declared in a Local interface are only available to clients that run in the same application of the Bean. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipmz/index.html) you have a more detailed list of what properties the Bean's client must meet to use his local services.

Answer (score -1):

Watch carefully the bean name for remote bean.

As an example, in WildFly the complete name to retrieve the remote bean contains "exported" - you can spot the actual name from server's startup log.